# What is legitimate way to typedef NSDictionary in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, foundation

I am trying to use Objective-C API in Swift and I have to typecast Swift Dictionary to NSSDictionary but if some way I can declare the NSDictionary in below written format, I can skim out redundant typecasting.

```
typedef NSDictionary* NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *;
```

In my Objective-C API there are several dictionaries and I want all them converted into above typdef.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are trying to redefine all `NSDictionary` as `NSDictionary<NSString *, id>`. That's a big no-no. Instead, create your own type:

```
typedef NSDictionary<NSString *, id> MyDictionary;

// Usage
MyDictionary * dict = [MyDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@1,@"one", @2,@"two", @3,@"three", nil];
```

Swift:

```
typealias MyDictionary = [String: Any]

let aDict: MyDictionary = [
    "one": 1, "two": 2, "three": 3
]

func doSomething(aDict: MyDictionary) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Almost all the dictionaries are arguments to function for e.g. 
`postMethod((NSDictionary *) parameters)` and I am trying to change this. Above mentioned method will require a lot of changes.